# Aerospike key digest using ruby client is not coming in proper format

Tags: java, ruby, aerospike

I am trying to store the key digest in the aerospike bin and I feel (not sure) if the format in which the ruby client is generating the digest is proper. Following are the details

```
Aerospike version:- 4.3
Client: [Ruby] aerospike - 2.4.0
ruby version:- 2.1.5
```

The key object which I get looks like below:

```
#<Aerospike::Key:0x0000000f5c8208 @namespace="namespace_name", @set_name="set_name", @user_key=#<Aerospike::StringValue:0x0000000f5c81b8 @value="key_value">, @digest=",E6\xF7/\xB8\xB7\xC85\x8B]$\xD8\t\xCAL\xB1\x94r\xA8">
```

The digest in the above object when stored in the Aerospike itself looks wierd (I am storing the digest as a list in the bin):

```
LIST('["�����KA/�N�d�v���1"]'
```

However, when using Java client it looks like this:

```
1D 20 2A AD 25 79 BB 53 3B 3F AC 70 9B 95 CA A3 6E FF 79 C4
```

Comment: The digest is a 20B result of hashing the set and PK through RIPEMD-160. It’s bound to not present well :). The Java client is pretty printing it as hex.

Comment: @RonenBotzerThe Java client returns bytearray when the digest is requested from the aerospike key. Is there any similar way to do it with Ruby as well

Comment: The Ruby client is also returning you an array of bytes. In both cases they'll return the same 20B digest for the same key. Are you asking about ways to pretty print this digest?